# LISP Lists sublist

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

function that only deletes the first element of each sublist in the list. For example,

Test 1:

- List is  `(10   (1  2  3)    (90  100)   122  156)`
- Output should be:  `(10   (2  3)  (100)   122  156)`

I know how to delete an element from the list but i don't know which function is used to delete  element from the sublist

Comment: Destructively delete inside the existing list, or return a new list with those elements missing?

Comment: return the new list with those elements missing like the first element for every sublist should be deleted

Comment: (1 (2 3 4) 5 ( 6 8 10) 9)
out should look like 
(1 (3 4) 5( 8 10) 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun butfirst (lst)
  (mapcar 
   (lambda (e) (if (consp e) (cdr e) e))
   lst))

(butfirst '(10 (1 2 3) (90 100) 122 156))
=> (10 (2 3) (100) 122 156)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i m kind of a newbie in the lisp world...can i ask you ! more?

Comment: Extol, it's useful, if you're having a problem, to figure out what you *can* do, and what you can't. Code is helpful for that. Did you learn anything from uselpa's post? Probably, but not as much as if you wrote some code yourself, and tried to get that code to work.

Answer (score 0):

yet another offer: without iteration, with a recursive algorithm.

```
(defun butfirst (lst)
  (cond
   ((null lst) '())
   ((consp (car lst))
    (cons (cdr (car lst))
          (butfirst (cdr lst))))
   (t (cons (car lst)
            (butfirst (cdr lst))))))
```